# GrideView.count inside column and Container not scroll (Flutter)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, layout

in my code I use from GrideView.count but it dos not scroll, I wrap entire column with Expanded widget it works but in release mode it shows a gray window and got error. please help me it takes my hours but not solve yet.

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 178 pixels on the bottom.

```
import 'package:doctor_yab/app/theme/AppColors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../components/buildStroy.dart';
import '../../../components/searchAndFilterBox.dart';
import '../../../routes/app_pages.dart';
import '../../home/controllers/tab_home_main_controller.dart';

class NavigationBarNewF extends GetView<TabHomeMainController> {
  const NavigationBarNewF({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          buildStroies(controller: controller),
          Container(),
        ],
            ),
            searchAndFilterBox(
          name: 'Mohammad Nabi HassanZada',
          subject: 'Doctor',
          onPressed: () {}),
            Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFEBEDFF),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  size: 24,
                  color: AppColors.primary,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Navigation',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF333E92),
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.cancel_outlined,
                  size: 24,
                  color: AppColors.primary,
                ),
              ],
            ).paddingSymmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 15),
        
            // Grid view
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
             physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              primary: false,
             
              children: [
                _customCart(
                    title: 'Drag Database',
                    color: 0xFFFFF0EC,
                    image: 'assets/png/Pills.png',
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.Drugs_Database);
                    }),
                _customCart(
                    title: 'Disease and Treatment',
                    color: 0xFFF0FFEC,
                    image: 'assets/png/hansaplas.png',
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.All_Dieases_Treatment);
                    }),
                _customCart(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.Blood_Donation);
                    },
                    title: 'Blood Donation',
                    color: 0xFFFFE2E1,
                    image: 'assets/png/Pills.png'),
                _customCart(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.Treatment_Abroad);
                    },
                    title: 'Treatment Abroad',
                    color: 0xFFB6E9FF,
                    image: 'assets/png/airplane 1.png'),
                _customCart(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.Pregnancy_Tracker);
                    },
                    title: 'Pregnancy Tracker',
                    color: 0xFFECFDFF,
                    image: 'assets/png/OBJECTS.png'),
                _customCart(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.Checkup_List);
                    },
                    title: 'Checkup Packages',
                    color: 0xFFFFF6D6,
                    image: 'assets/png/microskop.png'),
              ],
            ).paddingOnly(bottom: 30, right: 20, left: 20, top: 8),
          )
          ],
        ),
            ).paddingSymmetric(horizontal: 20)
          ]));
  }

  Widget _customCart({title, image, color, onTap}) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 130,
              height: 95,
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: Color(color),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              ),
              child: Image.asset(image),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 77,
              child: Text(
                title,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFF3F3F3F),
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  height: 0.97,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**in my code i use from GrideView.count but it dos not scroll, I wrap entire column with Expanded widget it works but in release mode it shows a gray window and got error. please help me it takes my hours but not solve yet.
this is my code:**

```
import 'package:doctor_yab/app/theme/AppColors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../components/buildStroy.dart';
import '../../../components/searchAndFilterBox.dart';
import '../../../routes/app_pages.dart';
import '../../home/controllers/tab_home_main_controller.dart';

class NavigationBarNewF extends GetView<TabHomeMainController> {
  const NavigationBarNewF({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          buildStroies(controller: controller),
          Container(),
        ],
            ),
            searchAndFilterBox(
          name: 'Mohammad Nabi HassanZada',
          subject: 'Doctor',
          onPressed: () {}),
            Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFEBEDFF),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  size: 24,
                  color: AppColors.primary,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Navigation',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF333E92),
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.cancel_outlined,
                  size: 24,
                  color: AppColors.primary,
                ),
              ],
            ).paddingSymmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 15),
        
            // Grid view
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
             physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              primary: false,
             
              children: [
                _customCart(
                    title: 'Drag Database',
                    color: 0xFFFFF0EC,
                    image: 'assets/png/Pills.png',
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.Drugs_Database);
                    }),
                _customCart(
                    title: 'Disease and Treatment',
                    color: 0xFFF0FFEC,
                    image: 'assets/png/hansaplas.png',
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.All_Dieases_Treatment);
                    }),
                _customCart(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.Blood_Donation);
                    },
                    title: 'Blood Donation',
                    color: 0xFFFFE2E1,
                    image: 'assets/png/Pills.png'),
                _customCart(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.Treatment_Abroad);
                    },
                    title: 'Treatment Abroad',
                    color: 0xFFB6E9FF,
                    image: 'assets/png/airplane 1.png'),
                _customCart(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.Pregnancy_Tracker);
                    },
                    title: 'Pregnancy Tracker',
                    color: 0xFFECFDFF,
                    image: 'assets/png/OBJECTS.png'),
                _customCart(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.Checkup_List);
                    },
                    title: 'Checkup Packages',
                    color: 0xFFFFF6D6,
                    image: 'assets/png/microskop.png'),
              ],
            ).paddingOnly(bottom: 30, right: 20, left: 20, top: 8),
          )
          ],
        ),
            ).paddingSymmetric(horizontal: 20)
          ]));
  }

  Widget _customCart({title, image, color, onTap}) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 130,
              height: 95,
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: Color(color),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              ),
              child: Image.asset(image),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 77,
              child: Text(
                title,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFF3F3F3F),
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  height: 0.97,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try to hide/remove mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, under the column? And reply here whether it's working or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the Expanded and adding SingleChildScrollView();

[SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

By adding the expanded does not mean that it is scrollable instead it means to render in the whole available space in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `SingleChildScrollView` widget as a parent of the `Column` widget.

Comment: it is not work i did it before, if i wrap first column to Singlechildscrollview it makes extra space in bottom, if i wrap second column in singlechildscrollview the Grideviewe.count not show

Comment: I've added a new answer. Try it that way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77088324/5451849

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Column in a `SingleChildScrollView` and make sure that `shrinkwrap` is set to `true` inside your GridView.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, It should be in this way:

```
    // Main Scroll View
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // Any widgets
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.orange),
          // Any widgets
          GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: const <Widget>[
              // Any widgets
              Card(child: Center(child: Text("01"))),
              // Any widgets
              Card(child: Center(child: Text("02"))),
              // Any widgets
              Card(child: Center(child: Text("03"))),
              // Any widgets
              Card(child: Center(child: Text("04"))),
              // Any widgets
            ],
          ),
          // Any widgets
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.green),
          // Any widgets
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: it dos not work, the gride view not scroll same error